# Matplotliib: Creating multi bar charts for multiple columns from a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts, seaborn

I have a Pandas dataframe with four columns; the first is a centretype (x axis) and I want the rest of the columns to be displayed as side by side columns for each centretype by year. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong, as I am getting only the values for 2019 but I want 2018 and 2017 displayed too.

[image]

[image]

```
df = c2

colors = ['steelblue','forestgreen','salmon']

ax = df.plot(kind='bar', color=colors, width=0.7, align='center', stacked=False, rot=60, figsize=(12,6), legend=False, zorder=3)


from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter, MaxNLocator
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))

plt.grid(zorder=0)
#plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.2))
plt.xlabel("Type of centre")
plt.ylabel("Number")
plt.title("")

ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('gainsboro')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('white') 
ax.spines['right'].set_color('white')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('gainsboro')

ax.yaxis.label.set_color('black')
ax.xaxis.label.set_color('black')

ax.title.set_color('black')

ax.patch.set_facecolor('white')

plt.savefig('images/figure1.png', dpi=300, facecolor=ax.get_facecolor(), transparent=True,  bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1)
plt.show()
data.shape
```

Comment: If I define `df` like `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3), columns=[2018, 2019, 2020], index=list("ABCDE"))` and run your code I get the desired output, namely [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3bVl.png). This means that you're either not using the data you think you do, or that you're using a specific pandas version with a bug in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your picture contains just one column is `df = c2`.
Apparently *c2* contains only one of columns from your DataFrame.
Delete this instruction.

As a test, I performed just:

```
df.plot.bar(width=0.7, rot=60, figsize=(12,6), legend=False);
```

getting the following proper picture, with 5 sets of bars, 3 bars each:

[image]

Start from just the above instruction and then decide which remaining
instruction should actually be executed.

In my opinion, the omitted parameters are not needed, because they
pass their respective default values.

Note also the semicolon at the end. Working under *Jupyter Notebook*
it is required to render just the picture.
Otherwise (without the terminating semicolon),
*<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at ...>* is printed over the picture.

Maybe you should also drop *legend=False* (stay with default *True* value and
print the legend).
Otherwise it is not clear what particular bars refer to.